# Difference btw url_launcher vs android_intent_plus

Tags: android, flutter

I'm a newbie in developing apps. I wanted to launch a URL upon button click. Found 2 methods.

1. via android_intent_plus

```
    void launchIntent(String url) async {
        AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(action: 'action_view', data: url);
        await intent.launch();
      }
```

2. via url_launcher

```
    void _launchURL(String url) async {
        if (await canLaunch(url)) {
          await launch(url);
        } else {
          throw 'Could not launch $url';
        }
      }
```

Whats the difference between the two? I know `android_intent_plus` works only on android. Is there anything else?

Comment: - Android Intent only works on Android
- Android Intent can also send files
- Url Launcher does what it saids, it launches URLs in all supported platforms
- Url Launcher does a similar thing like Android Intents as Intents are requiere to launch URLs

Comment: Android Intent can also send files-- Sending the files?? as in?

Comment: I'll recommend your "share_plus" (https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) as it implements Android Intents way better than Android Intent Plus

Comment: also... as a concept: URL Launcher works just like the <a href> hyperlinks from the Web, like a clickable link.